# Get count if value not null from left join table

Tags: sql

```
SELECT o.*, g.goods_tax_price_percent, p.*
  FROM `ecs_order_goods` AS o
     LEFT JOIN `ecs_order_goods` AS p
        ON p.product_id = o.product_id
     LEFT JOIN `ecs_goods` AS g
         ON o.goods_id = g.goods_id
     WHERE o.order_id = '93' ORDER BY goods_id
```

How do get total count of `g.goods_tax_price_percent` is not null value?

I tried
`SELECT COUNT(g.goods_tax_price_percent IS NOT NULL) AS tax_item`
is not working

## Example of my table

```
---------------------------
TABLE : esc_goods
----------------------------
id | goods_tax_price_percent
----------------------------
1  | NULL
2  | 10
3  | 30
4  | NULL
----------------------------
```

## Result that I want

I want `COUNT(g.goods_tax_price_percent IS NOT NULL) AS tax_item` = 2

Comment: COUNT doesn't  include NULL values so do `COUNT(g.goods_tax_price_percent)` (and then you need a GROUP BY)

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  You don't have an aggregation query but you are asking something about an aggregation function.  Very unclear what you want to count.

Comment: @GordonLinoff hi, I already update my question.. have a look.. sad to see so many downvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `count()`:

```
SELECT COUNT(g.goods_tax_price_percent) as tax_item
FROM ecs_order_goods o LEFT JOIN
     ecs_order_goods p 
     ON p.product_id = o.product_id LEFT JOIN
     ecs_goods g
     ON o.goods_id = g.goods_id
WHERE o.order_id = 93 ;
```

The `LEFT JOIN` could be an `INNER JOIN` for this query.

Comment: so the value of null will ignore? output will be 2?

Comment: `COUNT(<expression>)` counts the number of non-`NULL` values.